# Display html values in Text view android

Tags: android

How can i display html values in textview in android. 
Sample output response is in this link: http://pastebin.com/KYMTKAss .
Similarly i ve many classes and values. How can i fetch these html values into a string and display them in Textview. Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to encode the Strings properly, or how to show HTML?

Comment: I need to parse the above html response and get class values. In the above attachments we have different classes and each class has value assigned to it. I need to get values of each class. How can i do that.  Like for instance,<Div class=\"profile_pic_container\"> this class contains image. Like other class has message values, Name value. I need to get these values individually.  Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) already?

Comment: yes. This is working but we pass one html data and get the response. When i have more that 1 html tag(HTML class) how can i differentiate each class value.

Comment: then you need a parser... as @sunil-kumar-sahoo says Jsoup is a good solution

Comment: check out my post for a working example http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse HTML using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). The jar is about 132k, which is a bit big, but if you download the source and take out some of the methods you will not be using, then it is not as big. Have a look on [HTML Parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)